# Pattern matching on a closure variable in an anonymous fun predicate

Tags: erlang

I know, the title sucks... not sure how to explain what I'm asking, so how about some code?

The setup:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].
X = 5.
Y = 10.
```

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
lists:any(fun(Z) when Z == X -> true; (_) -> false end, L). => true
lists:any(fun(Z) when Z == Y -> true; (_) -> false end, L). => false
```

What I'd like to do is something like this sans the guard statement (I don't know why, just curious if it's possible.

I'm wondering if you can do something like this (Yes, I know having X in the fun head makes a local scoped variable):

```
lists:any(fun(X) -> true; (_) -> false end, L).
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This particular one could be written as:

```
lists:any(fun(Z) -> Z =:= X end, L).
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer your main question: it's not possible. In the heads of fun clauses, all variables are regarded as new, and will shadow any existing bindings in the environment. You have to use guards to match captured variables against parameter variables.